# Attach bidet to a toilet with a rigid pipe and remote shut off valve

Tags: plumbing, toilet

All the toilets in my house have a rigid pipe connection going straight into the wall or floor, with all the shut off valves in the garage. Is there any way to attach a bidet to a toilet like this?

[image: toilet connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do first is install a supply stop there.  Since you're plumbing anyway you'll have the pipe open and an extra shutoff is never a bad thing, especially in your case as you currently don't have a way to shut off the water at the point of use.  Having to run to the garage to stop a leaking toilet seems like asking for trouble.

[image]

The supply stop pictured above installs directly into 1/2" PEX.  You'll need a crimp ring and crimper to install it.  There are also push-on fittings for PEX that I have used a number of times successfully.

Install it just above the escutcheon plate at the floor.

All the add-on bidets I've installed have come with a 3/8" threaded tee like the one pictured below and a hose to tee off the existing toilet supply stop.

[image]

Connect the tee to your new supply stop, feed the bidet from one outlet, and the toilet from the second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You would attach the bidet fitting to the fill valve and then you'd have to cut the white Pex tubing to fit to the bottom of the bidet fitting. You'll need some special tools to reattach the fitting to the white Pex tube after shortening it. It's not a difficult job but if you're not comfortable doing plumbing work, get some additional help, leaks are not fun.